# Bluetooth printing from iPad?

Tags: ipad, printing

The company I work for had people out in the field doing data entry on their iPads.  We would like them to be able to print from the iPad to a bluetooth printer in their car, but I'm not sure if this can be done.  We tried using the HP Officejet 100 Mobile Printer, but while we can connect using bluetooth we have been unable to print.

Has anyone done this?  If so, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384177/ios-bluetooth-printer

Comment: your best alternative might be to try an AirPrint capable printer and a WAP

Answer (score 3):

@Jason's link to SO is correct - the out-of-the-box iPad will not support Bluetooth printing. However, there are receipt printers like [Blue Bamboo](http://www.zephyrhardware.com/Blue-Bamboo-Bluetooth-Printer-w-Card-Reader-for-iOS-_p_28.html) or the [Star Mobile printer](http://www.starasia.com/productshow.asp?ID=148), but these solutions might not be what you're looking for.

There are iBluetooth apps now in the iOS App Store - it's possible that the vendor no longer supports the Cydia version.

Another possible solution is an app like [PrintCentral](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/printcentral/id366020849?mt=8), which allows for printing wirelessly over 3G and WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

We use the Brother RJ4040 mobile printer and Print n share for our sales guys out on the road. Works really well and when we first introduced it the guys took to it quickly with no problems. The rj4040 has its own Wifi network so you can print straight to it from the ipad? Hope this may help, saw your question and had to answer!!

Comment: Is this just a receipt printer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem
An AirPrint printer will only work through a wireless network, this means you must have a network through a router.
When you are out of the office or home you are then out of the network range  so your ipad will switch over from wifi to 3G hence no network,so no printer.
The fixes are 
1 get a mobile wifi router which will need another Internet plan, (more money) 
2 get a Bluetooth printer, ( can't find any )
3 get an ipad three ( lots more money but it has personal hotspot )

So in other words it can be done but it will cost you.

Answer (score 1):

I just got off the phone with Apple. They informed me that the HP Officejet 100 mobile will NOT work using Bluetooth with my ipad 4. The young lady did tell me, however, that the HP Officejet 150 mobile printer will work. Unfortunately it is a bit costly at $400. Hope this helps.